# Question on relative clause

Tags: usage, relative-pronouns

I've been reading a online book where I saw this sentence:

> Even though I'm living alone, just by looking at your lifestyle which everything has to be done perfectly, personally I wouldn't follow it but I understand how you feel.

Is there "which" in "your lifestyle which" the correct relative pronoun to use there, or does it need changing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is an ill-phrased sentence even after setting aright _which_ there (it should be _in which_ or _where_.)

Comment: Maybe a better version would be— *Even though I'm living alone but just by looking at your lifestyle in which everything has to be done perfectly, I wouldn't follow it myself; but I understand how you feel. (I am not sure though what you mean by "but I understand how you feel.")*

Comment: And it isn't really about relative clause at all— for in no way does _which_ refer to the preceding _lifestyle_. It's merely an omission of preposition. Furthermore, how does _living alone_ contrast with _doing things perfectly_?

Comment: The sentence is trying to do the work of three sentences. "Even though I'm living alone, I understand how you feel. Just by looking at your lifestyle, *I see that* everything has to be done perfectly. Personally I wouldn't follow that style."